# (Qt C++) setw/setfill Equivalent?

Tags: c++, qt, int, hex

I have a noob question for you. I'm trying to convert an uint to a Qstring as hex. So far so good, however, I want the width of the string to be 8 characters long. In the past without Qt, I just used setw(8) and setfill('0'), but it appears that doesn't exist in Qt?

So...

```
a would be 0000000a
15 would be 00000015
```

How would I go about doing that simply?

My current IntToHex function:

```
void IntToHex(int num_int, QString &num_hex, int width)
{
    uint num_uint = num_int;
    num_hex.setNum(num_uint,16);

    if(num_hex.length()<width)
    {
        for(int i=1; i<=num_hex.length()-width; i++)
            num_hex.insert(0, "0");
    }
}
```

But this doesn't work :/

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer instead of editing the question.

Comment: BTW, I do this with QString::arg()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered my own question. Leaving it here for future questioners.

```
void IntToHex(int num_int, QString &num_hex, int width)
{
    num_hex = QString::number(num_int, 16);
    if(num_hex.size()<width) num_hex = QString(width-num_hex.size(), '0')+num_hex;
}
```

Comment: nice answer but actually you can skip the if condition.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking recently for a setw() equivalent in Qt (for testing purposes).  The equivalent is the read() method in the QTextStream.  But the way is used is a little different.

As an example if you have a date in a file in the format year-month-day like these (2014-10-20), if you want to read that date, but store it as a separate values year, month, day, in C++ would be something like this:

```
if(myfile.is_open())
{
    while (!myfile.eof())
    {
         myfile >> setw(4) >> year >>
              setw(1) >> dummy >>   // separation char
              setw(2) >> month >>
              setw(1) >> dummy >>   // another separation char
              setw(2) >> day;
    }
}
```

while using Qt Strings would be something like this:

```
if (myfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
{
     QTextStream in(&myfile);
     while( !in.atEnd()){
          year = in.read(4);
          dummy = in.read(1);  // separation char
          month = in.read(2);
          dummy = in.read(1);  // another separation char
          day = in.read(2);
     }
}
```

Or you can read the whole chunk or even the file and then process and split the data manually.  A note, unlike C++ standard which all file operations are done on the stream created by ifstream/ofstream, Qt split that in 2 separate actions.  One is the access to the file, performed by 
QFile and its methods, and the other is the QTextStream (shown) that handles the stream in that previously opened file.